# Messenger Register set twice, only receives message in one place, MVVM-Light

Tags: mvvm-light

I've got a weird problem using MVVM-Light in a WP8.1 universal app.  When the download folder has been changed, I am sending out a message via Messenger that contains the new StorageFolder download folder.

I am registered to receive this message in two different viewmodel constructors (one for the main page, one for a custom file manager page).  Instances of both have already been created.

When I run this in my emulator, everything works as it should.  I get the message on both viewmodels.  However, when I run this on my phone (Lumia 920 with developer preview), I only get the message on the main page, not the file manager page that even sends the message (from the page's own codebehind).

At a glance I'm wondering if there's a thread problem here due to the difference in speeds... but I also wonder if there's a bug on the ARM side of the MVVM-light toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I was using the MessengerInstance.Register method, I was the victim of a limitation of the Messenger system (not a bug exactly).  Someone else described it here exactly:

https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7640

Basically, I was using a lambda that included a parameter from outside the lambda statement, making it a class held with a weak reference.  This was garbage collected and then gone forever. Fixed by rewriting the entire thing...